# Changing SVG animation attributes of a specific path with javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, svg-animate

Making an SVG object that moves along a specific path, but would like to change the attributes of a specific circle on the path with javascript an jquery, specifically the animateMotion duration of each path, at the moment, the code does not seem to be working with buttons. I am not sure this JS snippet actually represents the changing of SVG attributes. The duration is already set in HTML, but how to amend the attributes of an already existing animation?

Should the whole animation be made with setting attributes from javascript and leaving the HTML empty?

```js
    function animate() {
        var circle = $("circle1");
        var circle2 = $("circle2");
        circle.setAttributeNS("dur",2);
        circle2.setAttributeNS("dur",4);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100">
  <path fill="none" stroke="lightgrey"
    d="M20,50 C20,-50 180,150 180,50 C180-50 20,150 20,50 z" />

  <circle id="circle1" r="5" fill="brown">
    <animateMotion dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"
      path="M20,50 C20,-50 180,150 180,50 C180-50 20,150 20,50 z" />
  </circle>
</svg>

<svg width="500" height="100">
  <path fill="none" stroke="lightgrey"
    d="M20,50 C20,-50 180,150 180,50 C180-50 20,150 20,50 z" />
  <circle id="circle2" r="5" fill="red">
    <animateMotion dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite"
      path="M20,50 C20,-50 180,150 180,50 C180-50 20,150 20,50 z" />
  </circle>
</svg>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Change duration" onclick="animate();">
```

Comment: Use setAttribute rather than setAttributeNS (or if you must use setAttributeNS add an initial argument of null, setAttributeNS takes 3 parameters, not two).

Comment: The third initial argument did not provide a functionable code. Might you add an answer to the question for the question to be useful.

Comment: Mostly, a property like this exists: $(this).find('animateMotion').attr('dur', '100s'); How could this be applied to each path specifically?

Comment: The issue was solved using the property above

Comment: @john_snow5214, you should post your answer so others may benefit. It was a bit unclear what you were going for, so your answer could help someone with your specific use case.